# unity says it can't convert (int,int,int) into a quartinon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

all I want to do it code a auto generating game like flappy bird but I am getting errors I have never heard of and as far as I researched I don't think anyone else has experienced these errors I got 2
Argument 3: cannot convert from '(int,int,int)' to 'quaternion'
Argument 4: cannont convert for 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'UnityEngine.Transfrom'

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public GameObject prefab;
    public int objectCount;
    public float spacing;
    public GameObject prefab2;
    public int Height;

    void Start()
    {
        var position = new Vector3();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++)
        {
             Instantiate(prefab, position, (0, Random.Range(-Height, Height), 0), Quaternion.identity);
            position.x += spacing;
        }
    }
    
}
```

I have already tryed turning it into a float and I did not work so am I missing something?

Comment: _Quaternion_ is the correct spelling FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no

```
Instantiate(GameObject, Vector3, (int,int,int), Quaternion)
```

I suppose you wanted to add random height to position instead setting it as a third parameter. Try

```
Instantiate(prefab, position + Vector3.up * Random.Range(-Height,Height), Quaternion.identity);
```

instead.

Also if you need to create Vector3 the "(x,y,z)" is not enough, you have to type "new Vector3(x,y,z)".

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of Instantiate you are using takes 4 parameters so it must match this:

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent);
```

The last two parameters are Quaternion rotation & Transform parent. Looks as though you need to put the Quaternion.identity as the second to last parameter and set the Parent transform as the last.

```
Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity, PARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

your are calling `Instantiate` with 4 parameters which has parameters as

```
Instantiate(GameObjectToInstantiate, PositionInVector3, RotationInQuaternion, transform);
```

for that reason unity is expecting `Quaternion` in third parameter but your are passing `(0, Random.Range(-Height, Height), 0)`